# Sending Initial pose to the Navigation Stack?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

There is tutorial for Sending Goals to the Navigation Stack in Ros wiki [here](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals). Is it possible to do the same thing for the initial position of the robot? if yes, how could I extract the actual pose of the robot  first and then use it for this propose?

Thanks for helping me out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296011/sending-initial-pose-to-the-navigation-stack?/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2018-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using, like the tutorial, the `base_link` frame of the robot then the initial pose is always `{0;0}`.

If you want the initial pose of the robot within the map reference frame then you can use a `tf listener` between `map` and  `base_link` before moving the robot and save the coordinates to use them when you need.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is based on what I get from the question.

1. if you want to change the initial position of the robot on launch. you can add the initial pose in the `xml` file. You might be using `amcl.launch.xml` in the amcl.launch. you can add the initial pose of the robot there as

   ```
      <arg name="initial_pose_x" default="0.0"/> 
     <arg name="initial_pose_y" default="0.0"/> 
     <arg name="initial_pose_a" default="0.0"/>
     <include file="$(find <package>)/launch/includes/amcl.launch.xml">
        <arg name="initial_pose_x" value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_y" value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
        <arg name="initial_pose_a" value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
    </include>
   ```

The above are the parameters for amcl node.

2. If you want ot track the position of your model in `xyz plane`, you can use the `/odom` topic for same. `odom` will give you the position and orientation of the robot.

I hope, I answered your question

---

Originally posted by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) with karma: 241 on 2018-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1